# Accessing/Using nested classes from other classes C#

Tags: c#, class, nested

I have a class in a folder in my namespace as:

```
using System;  

namespace mynamespace.myFolder1
{
   public class F1  
   {  
      // class properties...  
      // class methods...  

      public class F1_Nest  
      {  
          // class properties...  
          // class methods...  
      }  
}
```

Now I have to access class `F1_Nest` as from:

```
using System;  
using mynamespace.myFolder1;   

namespace mynamespace.myFolder2  
{  
   public class F2  
   {  
      // class properties...  
      // class methods...  

      // I have to access nested class F1_Nest here...  
   }  
}
```

How will I use/access class `F1_Nest` inside class `F2`?

Comment: Nested classes are only accessible through the parent name: `F1.F1_Nest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested class is just like a normal class, except it's definition resides *within* the containing class.  The result is that the containing class is almost like a namespace for the nested class.  You don't have to instantiate the containing class in order to use the nested class.  For instance:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyParentClass
    {
        public class MyNestedClass
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now you can instantiate it somewhere else like this:

```
MyNamespace.MyParentClass.MyNestedClass x = 
    new MyNamespace.MyParentClass.MyNestedClass();
```

The purpose of this, like namespaces, is for organization.  It's up to you as the designer whether or not you use nested classes instead of a flat class structure, but it can be convenient when you have a class whose meaning, definition, or usage is inextricably tied to the another class and doesn't have any relevance or meaning *outside* of that class.

For example, imagine you have a `Widget` class which has an `ID` property that's more than just a simple `int` or `Guid`...you might have a `WidgetID` enumeration, for example that could reside as a nested class in `Widget`.

Answer (score 0):

To access nested classes you need to do the following:

```
using System;  
using mynamespace.myFolder1;   

namespace mynamespace.myFolder2  
{  
    public class F2  
    {  
        // class properties...  
        // class methods...  

        void SomeMethod()
        {
            // no need to instantiate an object of F1 class
            var f1Nest = new F1.F1_Nest();
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Side note on style: please check out http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions and consider if "Hope it will help" significantly improve quality of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The nested class `F1_Nest` can be accessed in class `F2` as:

```
using System;  
using mynamespace.myFolder1;   

namespace mynamespace.myFolder2  
{  
   public class F2  
   {  
      // class properties...  
      // class methods...  

      // I have to access nested class F1_Nest here...  
      void F2_Method()  
      {
         F1.F1_Nest();  
      }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the object of F1_Nest as follows

```
F1.F1_Nest  objYourObjectVariableName=new F1.F1_Nest();
```